# Input button in MVC asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button, input, html.actionlink

How to use Input button for @Html.ActionLink?

In my cshtml I have this code:

```
<div>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to menu", "HomeController")
</div>
```

Now I whant to use instead hyperlink button (Back to menu), input submit button, so this button:

```
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Back to menu">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't - you can use css so the link will look like button, or you can utilize Url.Action and javascript instead. I.E.:

```
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Back to menu" onclick="window.location='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';return false" />
```

Comment: Between '@Url.Action("Registration", "LoginController")'; shows Syntax error and return false underline with red color. If I remove qutes ' '  return false become ok (blue), but then ..tion=@ underline equal (=) and shows syntax error...

Comment: I'm not sure in what context you used that (for example I don't have semicolon - ';' at the end).

Comment: I write like this: <input type="button" value="Back to Edit Menu" onclick="window.location = @Url.Action("Registracija", "LoginAdmin"); return false"/>     inside = shows Syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it, Ondrej Svejdar thanks for advice, I use javascript and works fine:

```
<input class="someCss" type="button" value="Back to Edit Menu" onclick="Redirect()"/>
```

And under button I use this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Redirect() {
        var url = "@Url.Action("Registration")";
        location.href = url;
    }
</script>
```

So result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="button" value="Button" />
```

value="button" />

Comment: Doesn't provide a solution for the problem at hand.

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. Please explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.